# excel: sum of currency in two columns

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I've got an expenses form for my work which, to be fair, is terrible.  I constantly have to fill them out and so I'm trying to add some formulae to speed up the process.

I want to sum the total money which would be a simple =sum().  However my problem is that the money is split into two columns | £ | p | which means that I end up with the pence column not over flowing into the pounds when it hits 100.  I cannot change the format of the form.

Example:

```
currently
     | £ | p |
     | 5 | 20|
     | 4 | 90|
Total| 9 |110|

required
     | £ | p |
     | 5 | 20|
     | 4 | 90|
Total| 10| 10|
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

Answer (StackOverflow wont let me answer for 8 hours...)

Sorted it :)

The £ column I've summed and added to the sum of the pence column divided by 100 rounded down to the nearest integer:

```
=SUM(POUND COLUMN)+ROUNDDOWN((SUM(PENCE COLUMN)/100),0)
```

and then in the pence total I've summed the pence column, divided by 100, and then found the remainder using the MOD function

```
=MOD(SUM(PENCE COLUMN),100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert one of the values e.g. multiply pence by 100 to work in pounds, or divide the pounds by 100 to work in pence.  You can do this in your SUM formula.

Ok for the Pounds Column I would do:

```
=SUM(B1:B2)+INT(SUM(C1:C2)/100)
```

And for the Pence Column I would do:

```
=MOD(SUM(C1:C2),100 )
```

Where B1:B2 is the range of pound values and C1:C2 is the range of pence values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't think I've been clear in the description, sorry.  Essentially the problem is that I need to keep the total as two separate cells.  I'll improve the description :)

Comment: oh think you've answered it yourself too!  Happy Excel'ing.